# How to Control Events from firing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, events

I have an Event that fires off a Welcome email whenever someone registers a new account on my website.

My problem is, I needed to create a "Create User" page on my admin section. Now every time I create a user from the admin section the email still fires off an email welcoming the new user.

This would be fine, but I need that email to say something else.

I don't want the Welcome email to fire when creating a user from the admin panel.

**How can I control this Event from sending the email?**

Code pretty much goes in this order:

**1. Event code:** *NewUser.php*

```
namespace App\Events;
... irrelevant classes
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use App\User;
class NewUser
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

**2. Listener:** *SendWelcomeEmail.php*

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\NewUser;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\NewUserWelcome;

class SendWelcomeEmail
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(NewUser $event)
    {
        Mail::to($event->user->email)->send(new NewUserWelcome($event->user));
    }
}
```

**3. Mail:** *NewUserWelcome.php*

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\User;

class NewUserWelcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Welcome To The Website')->markdown('emails.user.newuserwelcome');
    }
}
```

**4. Markdown email** would be next.

```
@component('mail::message')
# Greetings bla bla bla
```

**5. EventServiceProvider:** is making the call like this:

```
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\NewUser' => [
            'App\Listeners\SendWelcomeEmail',
        ],
    ];
```

**6. User model** I have the following relevant code:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {

    use Notifiable;

    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'created' => Events\NewUser::class
    ];
```

In my ***ADMIN SAVE USER FUNCTION* | UserController** *This is what I'm using to SAVE the New User From Admin Panel*: (No Event classes)

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function adminUserStore(Request $request){

        $newsupporter = User::create([
            'name'=> $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($quickpass),
        ]);

        return back()->with('success','The user has been created and a password reset email has been sent to them.');     

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been battling this one for quite some time.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What's the problem? Didn't get it.

Comment: The Welcome Email is sending when I create a new user from the admin panel. I don't want the Welcome email to send.  I only want the Welcome email to send when a user register theirselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try by adding a new nullable column for your user model, which would check if the user was added by admin or someone else;

```
 $newsupporter = User::create([
            'name'=> $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($quickpass),
            'added_by' => 'admin',
        ]);
```

And then create a check and send email only when the user was not added my admin,

```
public function handle(NewUser $event)
    {
       if(!$event->user->added_by == 'admin'){
            Mail::to($event->user->email)->send(new NewUserWelcome($event->user));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This sounds pretty good. I wanted to avoid adding more columns to the Users table, but using that `If statement` would allow me to send the Admin New User a different email with a password reset link. -- I'm going to try this out. I'll be back to let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would introduce two events instead of the one. Something along the lines of `AccountCreatedByUser` and `AccountCreatedByAdmin`. These events can then be handled by separate listeners, which will send separate e-mails. This will mean you'll have to fire these events manually instead of depending on the built-in `created` event. This can be done like so:
`event(new AccountCreatedByUser($user));`

Documentation for firing events manually can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#dispatching-events)